# Как сделать так, чтобы бот ждал сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
...
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Введите ваш город:')
...
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Проверьте правильность введённого города:')
...
```

Вот код. После сообщения "введите ваш город" юзер отправляет сообщение, бот должен прочитать это сообщение не как команду, а как ввод текста

только не бейте палками, я новичок, взял первый заказ для портфолио и столкнулся с трудностями, надеюсь на понимание :)
и да код я не умею вствлять, надеюсь поймете

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, ты запустил бота")
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Каталог")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Пополнить баланс")
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот-магазин.".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Каталог":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Магнит", callback_data='1item')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Пятёрочка", callback_data='2item')

        markup.add(item1, item2)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Каталог:', reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Пополнить баланс":

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В разработке')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю такой команды')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == '1item':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Введите ваш город:')
        if call.data == '2item':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'другое сообщение')


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Не понял, всмысле `не как команду, а как ввод текста`?

Comment: @E1mir когда я ввожу название города, бот воспринимает это слово как отдельную команду, не относящююся к 'Введите ваш город:'

Comment: Покажите полный код, иначе ничего не понятно, что там у вас бот не так понимает

Comment: @Nobody обновил

Comment: else: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю такой команды') - убери или обрабатывай по другому